# How to auto-sync Header in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, header, c99

Do you know if there is a build-in feature or free add-in for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 that easily generates C-Headers and keeps them in sync with their .c counterparts?
I have already looked at Visual Assist X, but I'm not really willing to pay money at the moment.

Comment: I saw one for C++ but not for C: http://www.lazycplusplus.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/) as a pre-build step to create .h files. You may have to alter it a bit to suit your needs.